# In Javascript, how can I get the "tags" of a string into an array?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
The quick brown #fox jumped over the #reallyBigFence.
```

The result should be: `['fox','reallyBigFence']`

All tags are spaceless and they start with the hash tag.

I'm new to regex, but I think this would work (not sure): `/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi`

What do I do with that regex? .match?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var resultarray = "The quick brown #fox jumped over the #reallyBigFence."
   .match(/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi);
```

The match method will return an array of found substrings (because the regexp has the global flag), otherwise `null` if nothing is found. Yet, it returns the full matching string and not the capturing groups so the above will result in `["#fox","#reallyBigFence"]`. As JavaScript does not know [Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you will need to fix it afterwards with

```
if (resultarray) // !== null
    for (var i=0; i<resultarray.length; i++)
        resultarray[i] = resultarray[i].substr(1); // remove leading "#"
```

Comment: It might be better to use `/#([^\s]+)/` or `/#(\w+)/` as the valid characters in a word may include hyphens and other characters not in `a-z0-9`.

Comment: @RobG `/#(\w+)/` is getting only `#lazy` here `"...jumped over the #lazy-dog"`

Comment: Yes, `\w` matches word characters, RegExp doesn't think hyphens belong in words. :-( I was just pointing out that you'll need to play with the pattern to get what you want since you haven't defined it explicitly. Perhaps `/#([\w-]+)/g` or similar.